# Magento - browse 4 tier category tree

Tags: php, magento, menu, categories

I'm trying to build some code on my magento site that will allow the customer to click through my product categories viewing the child categories on each consecutive page.

I have a code snippet below that will successfully works for the first 2 levels, but does not allow me to browse the childern of the second level (i.e.the 3rd level etc)

Can anyone assist in tweaking this code to allow me to browse 4 levels deep?

```
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();

$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');


    foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$subcat->getURL().'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add recursively the `$obj->getCurrentChildCategories()` for the child categories aswell, since your current foreach only iterates for the childs of the first one.
Store the foreach in a function and use it for the $cat object.

```
function cats($obj) {
    foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
         echo '<li><a href="'.$subcat->getURL().'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
         cats($subcat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! all sorted!!